# Responsive Bootstrap column fix using Smarty

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, smarty3

I'm making a video gallery using PHP, Smarty and Bootstrap. On extra small screens it will show one column, on small screens i want to show 2 columns and beyond that i want to show 3 colums

The content is dinamically generated, and because of this it will not always have the same height, so i need to correct the missaligment using extra rows or add clearfix resets

[image]

here is my html code:

```
<div class="row nopadding">
    {foreach $hoteles as $hotel}
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="hotel">
                <div class="player">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{$hotel['yid']}/mqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <a href="index/detalle/{$hotel['id']}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="movil">
                    <h1>{$hotel['titulo']}</h1>
                    <p class="distancia">{$hotel['distancia']}</p>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <p>{$hotel['mensaje']}</p>
                    <ul class="extras">
                        {foreach $hotel['extras'] as $extras}<li><span>{$extras}</span></li>{/foreach}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

The problem is that smarty doesn't know the screen size and the number of columns to show so i cannot calculate how to add the clearfix resets or split the information in several rows... any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar some time ago. I added classes: **col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2** to div and added **row** class for each of 6.

For example:

```
<div class="row nopadding">
{foreach $hoteles as $hotel name="hotels"}
    {if $smarty.foreach.hotels.iteration %6 == 0}
        <div class="row">
    {/if}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <div class="hotel">
            <div class="player">
                <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{$hotel['yid']}/mqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <a href="index/detalle/{$hotel['id']}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="movil">
                <h1>{$hotel['titulo']}</h1>
                <p class="distancia">{$hotel['distancia']}</p>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <p>{$hotel['mensaje']}</p>
                <ul class="extras">
                    {foreach $hotel['extras'] as $extras}<li><span>{$extras}</span></li>{/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {if $smarty.foreach.hotels.iteration %6 == 0}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Now it shows 1 item if screen is very small (**col-xs-12**), 3 items when screen is medium (**col-sm-4 col-md-4**), and 6 items when screen is large (**col-lg-2**)

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: Not quite the answer that i was looking for but still give me some new ideas... thanks